# Returning Stream from WebRequest

Tags: c#, stream, httpwebrequest

I'm having an issue when i return a Stream from a WebRequest, it says that the stream was closed, when i have everything in the same method then it works here is the code example:

```
public static Stream MethodOne()
{
            Uri uri = new Uri(url, true);
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = "GET";

            Stream responseStream = null;
            using (WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse())
            {
                responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            }
}
```

The other method is:

```
public static XDocument MethodTwo()
        {
            Stream stream = MethodOne();
            if (stream == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
            return XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
        }
```

The error that i get is where i try to create an xmlReader from the stream with the following message: **The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.**

Any idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your using statement calls Dispose on the Response before you read the stream.

I would return the WebResponse from Method one.

```
    public static XDocument MethodTwo()
    {

        WebResponse response = MethodOne();
        if (response == null)
        {
            response null;
        }

        try
        {
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
            return XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
        }
        finally
        {
            response.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

Update: Better solution

```
    public static XDocument MethodTwo()
    {

        using (var response = MethodOne())
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
            return XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
        }

    }

    public static Stream MethodOne()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(url, true);
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "GET";
        return request;
    }
```

This will ensure that your resources are disposed (even if an exception occures).

Comment: Nothing, this is exact code that i have ... so i dont do anything

Comment: @Alnedru In fact you do. `using` closes the stream.

Comment: Doing that i'm getting Cannot access a disposed object, when i try to do resonse.GetResponseStream :(

Comment: Remove the using part from `MethodOne` - The closing bracket from a using statement calls `Dispose()` and the WebResponse.Dispose() method calls Close(), so basically you are doing `Create WebResponse, Close WebResonse, Return closed WebResponse`

Comment: But if i will remove all disposing ... what does this will lead to, that they will stay open, or it doesn't matter in this case?

Comment: Let MethodTwo close your response (I did this with try/finally). Is is a common scenario. I.e. `System.IO.File.Open(...)` returns a stream and expects you to take care of it yourself. I just updated the answer a litte bit to bring in using again.

Answer (score 0):

As SchlaWiener pointed out, the problem you're facing is that the `using` statement calls `Dispose()` on the stream before you can read the stream. You should refactor your code as follows:

```
public static Stream GetResponseStream() 
{
    var uri = new Uri(url, true);
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    return response.GetResponseStream();
}

public static XDocument GetXDocument()
{
    using(Stream stream = GetResponseStream())
    {
        XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream);
        return XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
    }
}
```

This way, you'll make sure the stream is closed only after the read.